# How do i get propertySources from remote git repo in spring cloud config server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have the following classes

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the application.properties

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/user_name/microservices.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username==user_name
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=password
```

limit-service.properties as, this file is at the same level as application.properties

```
limits-service.minimum=8
limits-service.maximum=888
```

when i hit the url `http://localhost:8888/limits-service/default` the response i get is

```
{
name: "limits-service",
profiles: [
"default"
],
label: null,
version: "9675306e9b89f8f52bd26fe84eccf7c1fe8d34be",
state: null,
propertySources: [ ]
}
```

Every file is committed to the remote git repo mentioned in the application.properties url. I dont want to use my local git . I want the properties to be read from remote git.
I also want the properties in the limit-service to be displayed inside the propertySources above. Where am i going wrong ?

[image: Project Heirarchy]